# find the nearest location by latitude and longitude in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, spatial

Hi i'm trying find the nearest location by latitude and longitude in postgresql database.But when i run the below query it showing column distance does not exists.

```
ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist
LINE 1: ... ) ) ) AS distance FROM station_location   HAVING distance <...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "distance" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 218

CREATE TABLE station_location
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('location_id_seq'::regclass),
  state_name character varying NOT NULL,
  country_name character varying NOT NULL,
  locality character varying NOT NULL,
  created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  is_delete boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  lat double precision,
  lng double precision,
  CONSTRAINT location_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

SELECT  *,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(6.414478) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(12.466646) ) + sin( radians(6.414478) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM station_location
HAVING distance < 5
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: when you give `id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('location_id_seq'::regclass),` better rewrite it to `id bigserial` - save time

Comment: All of these answers are slow and needlessly complex. Please see my answer for how to do this with PostGIS. In the future, you should ask these questions on [dba.se]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
select * from (
SELECT  *,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(6.414478) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(12.466646) ) + sin( radians(6.414478) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM station_location
) al
where distance < 5
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: do you recommend adding indexes on `lat` and `lng` columns?

Comment: In what unit is the distance measured? Miles? Kilometeres?

Comment: IS the distance in kilometer ?.

Comment: This one is in miles, to change it to km change the value from 3,959 to 6,371.
Earth radius: 6,371 kilometres (3,959 mi).

Answer (score 70):

## PostGIS

Don't store lat and long on a table like that. Instead use an PostGIS geometry or [geography type](https://postgis.net/docs/geography.html).

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE TABLE foo (
  geog geography;
);

CREATE INDEX ON foo USING gist(geog);

INSERT INTO foo (geog)
  VALUES (ST_MakePoint(x,y));
```

Now when you need to query it, you can use [KNN (`<->`)](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) which will actually do this on an index.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY foo.geog <-> ST_MakePoint(x,y)::geography;
```

In your query, you explicitly have `HAVING distance < 5`. You can do that on the index too.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE ST_DWithin(foo.geog, ST_MakePoint(x,y)::geography, distance_in_meters)
ORDER BY foo.geog <-> ST_MakePoint(x,y)::geography;
```

This ensure that nothing is returned if all points lie outside of `distance_in_meters`.

Furthermore x and y are decimal numbers `ST_MakePoint(46.06, 14.505)`

Comment: wow, I did not expect a reply @Evan :) Thanks a bunch - I am new to PostGis and your answer to this question is on the money. I disapprove of the marked `correct` answer :)

Comment: @JohnJ if you have any questions check out [dba.se]

Answer (score 20):

You can use PostgreSQL's [cube](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html) and [earthdistance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html) extensions.

Enable them like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION cube;
CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;
```

Let's say your current location is `35.697933, 139.707318`. Then your query will be something like this:

```
SELECT *, point(35.697933, 139.707318) <@>  (point(longitude, latitude)::point) as distance
FROM station_location
-- WHERE (point(35.697933, 139.707318) <@> point(longitude, latitude)) < 3
ORDER BY distance;
```

Please note that the `distance` is in miles (by default).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: I confirm, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chanmix51/1999886), you will find how to declare a DOMAIN on the `point` type and how to override the `distance` operator to return the orthodromic distance.

Declare a `latlong` type inherited from `point`:

```
CREATE DOMAIN latlong AS point CHECK (VALUE[0] BETWEEN -90.0 AND 90.0 AND VALUE[1] BETWEEN -180 AND 180);
```

The orthodromic distance in kilometers (distance on a sphere with the earth radius):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION orthodromic_distance(latlong, latlong) RETURNS float AS $_$
     SELECT acos(
              sin(radians($1[0])) 
            * 
              sin(radians($2[0]))
            + 
              cos(radians($1[0])) 
            * 
              cos(radians($2[0]))
            * 
              cos(radians($2[1]) 
            - 
              radians($1[1]))
            ) * 6370.0;
$_$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Override the distance operator `<->` using this function when used with latlongs:

```
CREATE OPERATOR <-> ( PROCEDURE = orthodromic_distance
, LEFTARG = latlong, RIGHTARG = latlong
);
```

Now in your SQL queries, to find the nearest entities:

```
WITH
  station_distance AS (
    SELECT
      id AS station_id,
      point(lat, long)::latlong <-> point(6.414478, 12.466646)::latlong AS distance
    FROM station_location
    WHERE NOT is_deleted
  )
  SELECT
    sl.state_name,
    sl.country_name,
    sl.locality,
    point(sl.lat, sl.long)::latlong AS coordinates,
    sd.distance
  FROM
    station_location sl
    JOIN station_distance sd
      ON sd.station_id = sl.id
  ORDER BY
    distance ASC
  LIMIT 10
```

You probably want to store the position `lat` and `long` in the same field using the latlong type.

Answer (score 0):

The manual clarifies :

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in 
>   ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses;
>   there you must write out the expression instead.