# The diffrence in mysql and psql syntax - finding the closest geocoordinates

Tags: mysql, postgresql, geolocation, coordinates, psql

I found a psql code which looks like this:

```
select * from (
SELECT *,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(6.414478) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(12.466646) ) + sin( radians(6.414478) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM station_location
) al
where distance < 5
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 20;
```

[find the nearest location by latitude and longitude in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827468/find-the-nearest-location-by-latitude-and-longitude-in-postgresql)

The problem is I completely don't get it.
Before I used to use mysql and the syntax was completely different:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

[Find nearest latitude/longitude with an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/find-nearest-latitude-longitude-with-an-sql-query)

How to convert this mysql instruction into psql, so the user's longitude and latitude will be `startlng` and `startlat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not commenting on the calculations themselves, this "port" to PostgreSQL should work:

```
select * from (select SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (10 - 8), 2) +
POW(69.1 * (100 - 10) * COS(10 / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
from table) d where distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```