# How to join 2 tables with different but similar data which are Longitude & Latitude

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables,
1st table is the resorts info

```
Resorts |   Latitude   |   Longitude
Hemsedal     60.9282437   8.38348693
```

2nd table is my snow info

```
   Month   |   Latitude   | Longitude
   12/1/2022    63.125       68.875
  12/1/2022     60.875       8.125
```

The longitude and latitude of both tables are not exact. is there a way that i can join my resorts table with the closest latitude and longitude from the 2nd table?

Comment: Yes, but first of all you have to _define close_.

Comment: something like `SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.latitude LIKE '6%' AND table2.latitude LIKE '6%';`

Comment: @k1dr0ck, LIKE is poor in several ways. Probably wrong data type. Does also pick Latitude 6.333. LIKE '6%' if you have 60.0000 will not find 59.9999.

Comment: @jarlh i added another row in my second table which is the closest to resort hemsedal. how can i join those two together?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some products have built-in functions for gis/spatial distance.

Comment: @jarlh im using postgresql

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37827468

Comment: try this SELECT r.Resorts, s.Month, s.Latitude, s.Longitude
FROM Resorts r
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Month, Latitude, Longitude, 
           2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((r.Latitude - s.Latitude) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) + 
                         COS(r.Latitude * PI()/180) * COS(s.Latitude * PI()/180) * 
                         POWER(SIN((r.Longitude - s.Longitude) * PI()/180 / 2), 2))) 
           * 6371 AS Distance
    FROM SnowInfo s
    ORDER BY Distance ASC
) s 
Haversine formula

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Haversine formula* for calculating the distance between the locations. However, if you do much with latitude, longitude you would be better off installing PostGis (create extension postgis). It has all the necessary functionality for handling geographic data. In this case:

```
with r (id, resort, r_loc) as 
       ( select id, resort,  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),4326)::geography
           from resorts 
       )
    , s (id, dt, s_loc) as
        ( select id, snowed_on, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),4326)::geography 
            from snows
        ) 
select *, ST_Distance(r_loc, s_loc) distance 
  from r cross join s
 order by ST_Distance(r_loc, s_loc);
```

Alternately, you can go a step further and instead of storing longitude and latitude columns and doing the necessary conversion on each query do the conversion once on insertion and store the column as `geography` data type. So (apply the same for `snows` table):

```
create table resorts_g ( id       integer  generated always as identity
                                          primary key 
                       , resort   text
                       , loc      geography
                       );
```

The query then reduces to just the main query  above without the CTEs. If you occasionally need longitude/latitude as separate columns you can extract them individually or together:

```
select id, resort
     , ST_X(loc::geometry)  longitude
     , ST_Y(loc::geometry)  latitude  
 FROM resorts_g;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z39Cqadh) here with both versions and then some.